# Why Android ListPreference does not update entries and entryValues dynamically, after creating the dialog

Tags: android, dynamic, load, listpreference

I read and tested all that was able to find about loading dynamically ListPreference. The problem is that ListPreference doesn't update entries and entryValues after dialog shown. 
The scenery: OnCreate of SettingsFragment i get the proper ListPreference already defined in XML. On preference.setOnPreferenceClick I start bluetooth discovery. Getting all the discovered devices in a list, I then create two CharSequence[] and set entries and entryValues. But, because already Dialog opened, it does not show those new values as lis,d the only thing that shows are the values passed when creating the ListPreference. I've tries extending ListPreference and make a proc to pass the new list with entries, but doesn't update. Tried hiding the dialog on click, wait for the discovery to finish, update the list, and then show the dialog but no exit. Tried that i'm getting the correct ListPreference - i do. 
What do I do wrong??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider editing your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Noone with similar issue?